# IOS Charts crashes when data source has only 1 value

Tags: ios, ios-charts

I am not sure how `IOS Charts` should behave when there is only 1 value to display, but for me it crashes all the time with the error: `fatal error: Index out of range`

Here is where the problem is happening:

```
func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
    let period = getXValues()
    return period[Int(value)]
}
```

`value` comes as -1.

Did someone had this issue before ?

Or is there a way to display data only when there is minimum 2 values ?

Comment: were you able to get this...??

Answer (score 0):

```
func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
            
            let index = Int(value)
            if (index < labels.count && index >= 0 ) {
            return labels[Int(value)]
            }
            return ""
        }
```